# How can I teach someone to taste for the correct amount of salt in a dish?

Tags: salt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How much salt should I add to a dish?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/556/how-much-salt-should-i-add-to-a-dish)

After so many years of cooking, I can usually taste a dish and adjust it to find that point where the salt is just enough to bring out all the flavors without crossing over into oversalted. I find that I have a difficult time communicating that art to others. Are there any exercises or tricks I can teach people to learn this all important skill?

Comment: I think that post will cover it.

Comment: This question covers an entirely different ground than the other one.  It is discussing how to pass on your trained palate to others in quick and efficient method. The answers to the other question don't read as suitable explanations for this one. In other words, you couldn't take any of them and place it under this question and expect it to be accepted.

Comment: You're missing the obvious @sarge. If you ask "how much do I salt?" the answer is in that thread. If you ask "how do I teach someone to salt?", the answer is "go read that thread". Marking this as a duplicate does just that.

Comment: I grasp your point, but sending someone to that thread isn't going to the best way to teach someone to salt. The answer to every question on this site could just be "google it" but we all know that this site exists because that isn't the best answer to the problem, and in this case, read that thread isn't the best answer to how do I teach this person in front of me how to salt food correctly.

Comment: @sarge  I'm pretty much the last person to recommend closing a question--I'd rather improve it, answer it, make it more relevant, emphasize an angle, or just tolerate it and see what happens...but this was really a duplicate.  If you read that thread, it's a thorough answer to the complexity of understanding, learning, and implicitly teaching about salting to taste.

Comment: What I was looking for was not so much how to convince people to salt to taste, as to learn how to train their palate, which isn't well covered in that thread. For example, one thing I've tried that didn't work very well was to give someone 4 glasses of water. One left plain, and ask them to salt the other 3 as if it was soup - one slightly undersalted, one on point, and one just over. I thought this was going to be genius, but with the totally neutral taste of water, the salt is so dominant that it is confusing.